# Split a Dataframe based on column with different record types

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
RecordType    SSID    AcheivementLevel  ScaleScore
1             4234    1                  32
1             4321    4                  43
2             3432    2                  23
2             8878    2                  43
6             9809    3                  65
6             7807    2                  34
```

I am trying to split the dataframe by different record type. So, there would be columns of Achievement Level and ScaleScore for each Recordtype. What I was doing was creating a dataframe that contained each recordtype and then merging them on the SSID and joining them with a left join. Is there a quicker way to do this? I was thinking that maybe you could use stack and unstack, but I get confused with how to use it properly.

Comment: What are you trying to do with each split? Is this ```df.groupby('RecordType')``` not sufficient for your use-case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC you want separate DataFrames for each `RecordType` If that is correct you can use dictionary comprehension with `groupby`

```
dfs = {k:v for k,v in df.groupby('RecordType')}
```

You can call each frame by the record type:

```
print(dfs[1])

   RecordType  SSID  AcheivementLevel  ScaleScore
0           1  4234                 1          32
1           1  4321                 4          43
```

Comment: `dict(list(df.groupby('RecordType')))` is shorter ;)